# Only low screen resolution available

Tags: drivers, display, display-resolution

Ok, I know how it sounds. I'm not that dumb. But, I have a 1600x1200 external display on a nvidia gtx 260m and the resolution wont go past 1024x768. *Ubuntu 14.04 BTW

Comment: Are you using nVidia drivers?

Comment: I'm using the default drivers when you do a fresh install.

Comment: read this tutorial https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution

Comment: Open a terminal and run `sudo apt-get install nvidia-352 nvidia-prime` now reboot and you can use the `nvidia-settings` app to set up you GPU.

Comment: Take a look at my corrected answer. mark kirby contributed to it, so it cannot fail.

Comment: I did the sudo apt-get forthe nvidia-prime comment, then, when I rebooted, my machine got stuck in a login loop. I'd sign in, the screen would crash and kick me back to the login screen. I'm reinstalling Ubuntu now.

Comment: Try driver version, 340, see tomasz answer or `sudo apt-get install nvidia-340` You don't need to reinstall because of a log in loop, just post back here and I will gove instructions to fix it, nice and easy. Also don't forget to tag users like this @markkirby or we won't get notified.

Answer (score 2):

Go to [nVidia download site](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us) and follow these steps.

Once you have downloaded the driver, change to the directory containing the driver, if this is `downloads` run

```
cd ~/downloads
```

In order for the installer to work, you need to make it executable.

```
chmod +x _file_name_
```

_file_name_ is the file name, eg. NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-340.96.run

Install the driver by running

```
sudo sh ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-340.96.run
```

Or in abstract terms `sudo sh ./_file_name_`

One of the last installation steps will offer to update your X configuration file. Either accept that offer, edit your X configuration file manually so that the NVIDIA X driver will be used, or run in terminal

```
nvidia-xconfig
```

You can also check in Synaptic packet manager.

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

On my laptop Synaptic has a choice of nVidia drivers. The one that nVidia website chooses for your card is 340, ie. the file `NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-340.96.run` for 64-bit architecture. It's present in Synaptic, the package is `nvidia-340` but the one on the site is 3 days younger, so you may prefer to install that one.

Comment: No worries, I hope you get some upvotes. We should remove these comments as they add nothing important to your answer.

Comment: Ok. I just got The Deleter Badge.